# Add a class to a th

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

It's easy enough to add a class to a td in a webgrid, for example:

```
new WebGridColumn {
    ColumnName= "Owl.Species",
    Header= "Scientific Name",
    Style= "sci-name"
}
```

The style tag adds the class "sci-name" to the `td`. How can I add a class to the `th` for that column without using jQuery which wouldn't be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do it.  You can't even extend the WebGrid classes, as their methods aren't marked virtual.  The best way I can think of is to use some CSS, `nth-child` to target the `th` element by its index.

```
<style type='text/css'>
    table thead tr th:nth-child(2) {
        background: yellow;
    } 
</style>
```

Still not ideal, but I think better than using JQuery.

Comment: This is still the *best* way to handle what is a very obvious oversight on Microsoft's part.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using of `Javascript` code as below, it is easiest way.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3fscqh5k/)

```
$("table tr th:nth-child(n)").addClass("col-md-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `headerStyle` property of `WebGrid.GetHtml` Parameters for this

Eg:

[image]

Hope this helps!!!